# Rails where is en.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale

Where can Ifind the default em.yml file. I know for translated files on GitHub but I would like to have EN version. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find en.yml for dates and times in

```
activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
```

and active record validations messages in

```
activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be in RAILS_ROOT\config\locales

Comment: This file is only a sample. I would like to have en.yml with all the variables.

Comment: All the variables would depend entriely on what text you want translated on your site. If you want something that has a lot of translated text, look through Redmines locales: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/show/trunk/config/locales

Comment: I would like to translate all built in words (activerecord, controller...).